# How to route default traffic to another specific IP on a TP-Link router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing, routing-table

I have a TP-Linkk router TD-W8960N 300Mbps Wireless N ADSL2+ Modem Router, which I use to connect to the internet via PPPoE. I have a backup internet connection with its own router, connected to the tp-link one through a LAN cable.

- tp-link 192.168.1.1
- backup router 192.168.1.2

What I want is changing the routing table when the first PPPoE connection is down, and routing all the incoming traffic on the tp-link to the second router, but I'm not figuring it out how. What I did is connecting via the telnet and do the following:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
81.174.0.21     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp2
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp2
 > route delete default 0.0.0.0
Invalid destination IP address
 > route add default 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.2
Invalid destination IP address
 > route add 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.2
Please at least enter gateway IP or interface
```

I also tried to add it via the HTTP interface, but it tells me that `0.0.0.0` is an invalid address. Maybe I can't do it with this specific router and its firmware, but I don't know. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You definitively confirmed my doubts: on this kind of low budget models it's improbable you can tweak to such an extent. can you answer it officially so that I can flag it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality would be available if you decide to install a third party firmware such as openwrt. This is not an easy process (at least the first time) but will give you a lot more flexibility. There is documentation available for your router model here:
https://openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/td-w8960n

Bear in mind that the DSL modem will not work on your version of router if you install openwrt on it, due to driver availability and licencing.

Answer (score 1):

In most of these routers like this (all in one's for Cable/DSL) the route table is not directly editable, and if it is the "default" entries are typically locked and cannot be edited.

Basically you would need a DD-WRT/Tomato compatible router to act as the "main" router, or get a DSL router with the capability of a backup WAN connection built in.

The other option would be to use something like a RPi or Linux router box in front of the two routers and let it manage the routes. Consumer grade routers are not intended to perform this level of functionality .